# Using pyWin32 without installing it

Tags: python, windows, installation, console, pywin32

Is it possible to use pyWin32 without installing it?
I would like to include it into python's interpreter folder. 
I have managed to use Python interpreter without installing it (simply installing it and copy&pasting installed directory into my product).
I need also the same with pyWin32.

My objective is:
Client receives a folder with a script (batch) which will run python program in a console. The client does not have to install python, pywin32, nothing. What he needs is to copy and paste my product and run the console-based program.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My objective is: Client receives a folder with a script (batch) which
>   will run python program in a console. The client does not have to
>   install python, pywin32, nothing. What he needs is to copy and paste
>   my product and run the console-based program.

I would suggest something along the lines of using pyinstaller or any other python code to executable converter.

http://www.pyinstaller.org/

> PyInstaller is a program that freezes (packages) Python programs into
>   stand-alone executables, under Windows, Linux, Mac OS X, FreeBSD,
>   Solaris and AIX. Its main advantages over similar tools are that
>   PyInstaller works with Python 2.7 and 3.3—3.5, it builds smaller
>   executables thanks to transparent compression, it is fully
>   multi-platform, and use the OS support to load the dynamic libraries,
>   thus ensuring full compatibility.

To me it seems this would suit your/your clients needs quite well. Furthermore pyinstaller is easy to use.